# Google Vr service Aframe

Tags: javascript, html, aframe, webvr, google-vr

I'm using Aframe in AR web App, it works great but on the Android device with Chrome, I always have the 'Google Vr Installation Service Warning' that pops up. I really don't need that. Doesn't anyone know how to get rid of this alert?
I guess somehow Chrome recognize the Aframe scripts and understand that my Web app is an AR XP, but if anyone knows a trick to give chrome a wrong information so that alert doesn't shows up, it would be very helpful !!

Comment: Something like [this issue](https://github.com/googlevr/gvr-android-sdk/issues/362)?

Comment: Yes exactly that kind of warning. It appears at launch of my Aframe web App.